# Using google form's pre-filled link as api to submit contact information

Tags: javascript, forms, google-forms

I am working on a website, but we do not have a backend.
So for the contact form to make it work I want to use `google form pre-filled link` and send contact details to google form using `javascript`.
Here is the code form contact form -

```
   <form action="#"  method="post" id="contactForm" novalidate="novalidate">
        <div>
           <div>
              <div>
                 <input  name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name">
              </div>
              <div>
                 <input name="email" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter email address">
              </div>
              <div>
                 <input name="subject" id="subject" type="text" placeholder="Enter Subject">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div>
                 <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="5" placeholder="Enter Message"> 
                  </textarea>
               </div>
             </div>
            </div>
       <div>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
       </div>
   </form>
```

I want to write a script to submit this contact form to google form using a pre-filled link.